# Insure uniqueness of two columns if a third is true

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

```
| row (int)     | thingy_a_id (int)     | thingy_b_id (int)     | bool  | bunch_more_cols   |
|-----------    |-------------------    |-------------------    |------ |-----------------  |
| 1             | 6                     | 2                     | 0     |                   |
| 2             | 3                     | 3                     | 0     |                   |
| 3             | 2                     | 4                     | 0     |                   |
| 4             | 2                     | 4                     | 0     |                   |
| 5             | 2                     | 4                     | 1     |                   |
| 6             | 6                     | 2                     | 0     |                   |
```

In a database I'm creating I need a combination of two columns to be unique BUT only if a third is true. So that in the example above, it's ok that row 3 & 4 have the same thingy a and b cols because bool is False (0). And it's also ok that row 5 has the same thingy a & b cols as 3 & 4 because it's the only one that's bool is true (1). And, it'd be ok if yet another row was committed where thingy_a_id is 2, thingy_b_id is 4 AND bool is False (0).

What I need to prevent is ANOTHER row being committed where thingy_a_id is 2, thingy_b_id is 4 AND bool is True (1).

Can this be done with mySql? How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as concerned, MySQL does not support partial unique index (unlike other databases such as Postgres).

One way to work around this would be to replace `0` in `bool` column with `null`s: as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-storage-engine-index-characteristics), *a `UNIQUE` index permits multiple `NULL` values for columns that can contain `NULL`.*

So you would first ensure that the column is declared as `null`able, and turn all `0`s to `null`:

```
update mytable set bool = null where bool = 0;
```

Then you can create the unique index:

```
create unique index mytable_idx on mytable(thingy_a_id, thingy_b_id, bool);
```

With this set-up in place, you can rest assured that no duplicate will happen on `(thingy_a_id, thingy_b_id)` when `bool` has value `1`, and that they are allowed when `bool` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Yes, the key aspect here is about "partial indexes". Unfortunately MySQL does not implement them. +1

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar! I've confirmed this is working as expected in my code. LIttle weird having to set NULL instead of 0. But, it works! Many thanks!

Comment: In MySQL 8.13+ you can keep `bool = 0` and define a functional unique key like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a5dc9574b17adf275bf3236092f9a63)

Comment: Thank you @PaulSpiegel! MySql 8 is a little new for my taste. I'm going to probably roll a 5.7 compatible solution for now. But, that's really great info, thanks!

Comment: in 5.7 you can "exploit" a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1eee2bc91ce8e554db473668629e01f8)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: both are good solutions, I think that you should post them as an answer so it can be useful for others (not everyone reads the comments).

Comment: @GMB - I'm fine if you incorporate it into your answer.